# Xss filtering of single quote

Tags: xss, javascript, reflected-xss

**Any hint Here**

> Bypass filtering of single quote

http://leettime.net/xsslab1/stage--08.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty unclear what exactly you want to know.
If you want a hint on how to bypass a single quote (or any character filter), you may want to try a different representation of said character. Check out URL-encoding for example.

Comment: i used encoding ,double encoding and escape char but not work

Comment: If you rephrase your question instead of posting a link to some CTF challange, so it contains a problem you want to solve, maybe we can help you.

The problem here is: There are several methods for bypassing filter but no general answer to that question, as the filter-methods put in place greatly vary from website to website. And this is not a free puzzle solving service.